# Deep SubQuery Unknow column in where clause

Tags: mysql

3rd deep SELECT query return multiple row so i need wrap it with a SELECT Count(*) to return row count.

I know mysql will not correlated if more than 1 deep level sub query. But i dont know how to fix it.

```
SELECT U.uid, 
       U.ulogin, 
      (SELECT Count(*) 
      FROM   (SELECT Count(R.uid) 
            FROM   users R 
                   INNER JOIN deps D 
                           ON D.duid = R.uid 
            WHERE  R.uref = U.uid 
                   AND D.dstate >= 1 
            GROUP  BY D.duid 
            HAVING Sum(D.dzd) >= 100) AS MULROW) AS ROWCOUNT 
   FROM   users U 
       LEFT JOIN addinfo A 
            ON A.auid = U.uid 
   ORDER  BY ROWCOUNT DESC 
   LIMIT  5
```

"Unknow column U.uID in where clause"

Comment: Please put your code in the code block.

Comment: Sorry. Iam new here. I put it in block

Comment: In general, correlated subqueries can usually be converted to joins. Try writing this using a join instead.

Comment: I dont know. Please fix help me